# PostgreSQL - Query Optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have this below query which takes about 15-20 secs to run.

```
with cte0 as (
    SELECT
        label,
        date,
        CASE
            WHEN
                Lead(label || date || "number") OVER (PARTITION BY label || date || "number" ORDER BY "label", "date", "number", "time") IS NULL
            THEN
                '1'::numeric
            ELSE
                '0'::numeric
        END As "unique"
    FROM table_data
    LEFT JOIN table_mapper ON
        table_mapper."type" = table_data."type"
    WHERE Date BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - 1) and current_date - 1
)
SELECT 'MTD' as "label", round(sum("unique") / count("unique") *100,1) as "value" FROM cte0 WHERE "date" BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - 1) AND current_date -1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week' as "label", round(sum("unique") / count("unique") *100,1) as "value" FROM cte0 WHERE "date" BETWEEN date_trunc('week', current_date - 1) AND current_date -1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FTD' as "label", round(sum("unique") / count("unique") *100,1) as "value" FROM cte0 WHERE "date" = current_date -1
```

In the table `table_data` I have a index on `date` column.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_cli_date
  ON table_data
  USING btree
  (date);
```

#### Table Definition (`\d table_data`)

```
Table "public.table_data"
      Column      |          Type          | Modifiers
------------------+------------------------+-----------
 date             | date                   | not null
 number           | bigint                 | not null
 time             | time without time zone | not null
 end time         | time without time zone | not null
 duration         | integer                | not null
 time1            | integer                | not null
 time2            | integer                | not null
 time3            | integer                | not null
 time4            | integer                | not null
 time5            | integer                | not null
 time6            | integer                | not null
 time7            | integer                | not null
 type             | text                   | not null
 name             | text                   | not null
 id1              | integer                | not null
 id2              | integer                | not null
 key              | integer                | not null
 status           | text                   | not null
Indexes:
    "ix_cli_date" btree (date)
```

**Table Definition (`\d table_mapper`)**

```
 Table "public.table_mapper"
   Column   | Type | Modifiers
------------+------+-----------
 type       | text | not null
 label     | text | not null
 label2     | text | not null
 label3     | text | not null
 label4     | text | not null
 label5     | text | not null
```

#### EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query

```
Result  (cost=184342.66..230332.86 rows=3 width=64) (actual time=23377.923..25695.478 rows=3 loops=1)"
  CTE cte0"
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=121516.06..156751.65 rows=612793 width=23) (actual time=14578.000..18985.958 rows=696157 loops=1)"
          ->  Sort  (cost=121516.06..123048.04 rows=612793 width=23) (actual time=14577.975..17084.405 rows=696157 loops=1)"
                Sort Key: (((table_mapper.label || (table_data.date)::text) || (table_data."number")::text)), table_mapper.label, table_data.date, table_data."number", table_data."time""
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39480kB"
                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=11.96..37474.21 rows=612793 width=23) (actual time=1.449..3308.718 rows=696157 loops=1)"
                      Hash Cond: (table_data."type" = table_mapper."type")"
                      ->  Index Scan using ix_cli_date on table_data  (cost=0.02..29036.36 rows=612793 width=38) (actual time=0.141..946.648 rows=696157 loops=1)"
                            Index Cond: ((date >= date_trunc('month'::text, ((('now'::text)::date - 1))::timestamp with time zone)) AND (date   Hash  (cost=7.53..7.53 rows=353 width=25) (actual time=1.275..1.275 rows=336 loops=1)"
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 15kB"
                            ->  Seq Scan on table_mapper  (cost=0.00..7.53 rows=353 width=25) (actual time=0.020..0.589 rows=336 loops=1)"
  ->  Append  (cost=27591.00..73581.21 rows=3 width=64) (actual time=23377.920..25695.467 rows=3 loops=1)"
        ->  Aggregate  (cost=27591.00..27591.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=23377.917..23377.918 rows=1 loops=1)"
              ->  CTE Scan on cte0  (cost=0.00..27575.68 rows=3064 width=32) (actual time=14578.052..22335.236 rows=696157 loops=1)"
                    Filter: ((date = date_trunc('month'::text, ((('now'::text)::date - 1))::timestamp with time zone)))"
        ->  Aggregate  (cost=27591.00..27591.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1741.509..1741.510 rows=1 loops=1)"
              ->  CTE Scan on cte0  (cost=0.00..27575.68 rows=3064 width=32) (actual time=20.009..1522.352 rows=168261 loops=1)"
                    Filter: ((date = date_trunc('week'::text, ((('now'::text)::date - 1))::timestamp with time zone)))"
        ->  Aggregate  (cost=18399.11..18399.13 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=576.029..576.030 rows=1 loops=1)"
              ->  CTE Scan on cte0  (cost=0.00..18383.79 rows=3064 width=32) (actual time=9.308..546.735 rows=23486 loops=1)"
                    Filter: (date = (('now'::text)::date - 1))"
Total runtime: 25710.506 ms"
```

**Description :**

I'm taking the unique count and repeated count from the `table_data` and this where `LEAD` helped me out where I give the value 0 for the last repeated value of a column.

Suppose I have 3 `x` in a column. I give `1` value to the first 2 `x` and the 3rd `x` is given 0.

Actually through a `cte` I'm taking the entire rows from the table `table_data` and doing some calculation using the lead and concatinating the strings for a defined date range where each row `1` and `0` value is defined as per the criteria.

If the lead is null it'll be counted as 1 and if it is not null then 0.

And the I return 3 rows `MTD`, `Current Week` and `FTD` respectively with a calculation on taking the `sum()` I got from the lead and the `count(*)` entire rows.

For MTD I have the sum and count for the current month.

For Week - It's the current week and FTD is for yesterday.

Comment: You perform this string concatenation : `Lead(label || date || "number") OVER (PARTITION BY label || date || "number" ORDER BY "label", ...` Only to detect the begin of groups ? Why not use the _raw_ fields instead ?

Comment: I don't see a primary key in your table definition. Any other constraints or indexes missing? It's better to show what you get with `\d table_data` in `psql` instead of some hand-crafted surrogate.

Comment: Actually I'm a newbie. Do I need to run `\d table_data` in SQL Editor? And I didn't create any column for the primary column by the way.

Comment: [psql](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/psql/info) is the default command line interface of PostgreSQL. Every table should have a [primary key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS). Also, it's best *not* to use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers.

Comment: Good. What's missing is a description. Please add some explanation what the query is supposed to achieve.

Comment: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39480kB => make sure your work_mem is above this value (defined in postgresql.conf)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I've updated the same. Of course the work_mem is above the value. As I've haven't defined any Primary Key for the table is there anything wrong that table will not perform at it's best?

Comment: You are using two tables, the definition for `table_mapper` is missing. Also, there should probably be a [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) defined. Your description does not tell much about the purpose of the query. How is the sort order defined? Why do you care about the previous row?

Comment: Storing date and time separately is not very sexy either, designwise.

Comment: There is no column `label` anywhere?

Comment: @joop: Can make sense for two times and one date ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I've updated the table_mapper too. You can ignore the other columns names as I don't want to put the original column names as it is kinda restricted and official for me. Only column now I map is with `type` which is common in both `table_data` and `table_mapper`. And I'm using lead and assigning value considering a previous rows is because that's the easiest way I found to calculate the unique values where I got the help from this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907582/postgresql-assign-value-to-each-row-based-on-criteria).

Comment: {label,date,time,number} appear to be a candidate key here (maybe without the number) BTW: two times would also cause fold-over worries (and/or constraints: time_end >=time_begin)

Comment: `Only column now I map is with type which is common in both table_data and table_mapper.`? So, `label` comes from `table_mapper` or not?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. Yes, label comes from the table_mapper. I've corrected that in the `\d table_mapper` too.

Comment: OK. Why the `LEFT JOIN`? Are there types in the main table that can be missing in `table_mapper`. (If not, you should have a [fk constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) there.

Comment: Yes. There are rows that'll be missing in table_mapper hence I've used `LEFT JOIN`. But I don't know anything about the FOREIGN KEY Constraint. Neither I did mention it anywhere while I created the table or what ever. This is where I heard about it.

Comment: Can there be two types resulting in the same `label`? Do you want to group multiple types that have no label (and therefore find no row in `table_mapper`)?

Comment: And finally, your version of Postgres should be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT d.thedate
        , lead(m.label) OVER (PARTITION BY m.label, d.thedate, d.number
                              ORDER BY d.thetime) AS leader
   FROM   table_data d
   LEFT   JOIN table_mapper m USING (type)
   WHERE  thedate BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - 1)
                  AND current_date - 1
   )

SELECT 'MTD' AS label, round(count(leader)::numeric / count(*) * 100, 1) AS val
FROM   cte

UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week', round(count(leader)::numeric / count(*) * 100, 1)
FROM   cte
WHERE  thedate BETWEEN date_trunc('week', current_date - 1) AND current_date - 1

UNION ALL
SELECT 'FTD', round(count(leader)::numeric / count(*) * 100, 1)
FROM   cte
WHERE  thedate = current_date - 1;
```

The CTE makes sense for big tables, so you only scan it once. For smaller tables it may be faster without ...

Using `thedate` instead of reserved word `date` (in standard SQL).
`thetime`, `uni` instead of `time`, `unique`. Etc.

Simplified the `lead()` call. You get a value or NULL for the leading row. That seems the be the only relevant information.
It's a pointless waste to repeat columns from the `PARTITION` clause in the `ORDER BY` clause of a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Building on that, `count(leader) / count(*)` instead of `sum(uni) / count(uni)` is a bit faster. `count(column)` only counts non-null values, while `count(*)` counts all rows.

The condition for the first term of the `UNION` query was redundant.

More advice and links about data definition in the comments to the question.

#### Table design / Indexes

You should have primary keys. I suggest [`serial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) or `IDENTITY` column as surrogate PK for `table_data`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_data ADD COLUMN table_data_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Make `type` the primary key of `table_mapper` (also needed for the following FK constraint):

```
ALTER TABLE table_mapper ADD CONSTRAINT table_mapper_pkey (type);
```

Add a foreign key constraint for `type` to enforce referential integrity. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_data ADD CONSTRAINT table_data_type_fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES table_mapper (type)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

For ultimate read performance (at some cost for writes), add a multi-column index to possibly allow [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) for above query:

```
CREATE INDEX table_data_foo_idx ON table_data (thedate, number, thetime);
```

Comment: It's that I need to change the `date` column to `todate` or I can just simply use it like "date" as "thedate"? And it did reduce the time to 12s.

Comment: I suggest to use *any* other name for the column that is not a reserved word (or basic type name): `ALTER TABLE table_data  RENAME "date" TO my_new_column_name;`. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

As your query is written, you are referring to the CTE three times.  Instead, you can use conditional aggregation if you are willing to have the values in three columns rather than three rows:

```
SELECT round(sum("date" BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - 1) AND current_date -1 then "unique" else 0 END)) /
             sum("date" BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date - 1) AND current_date -1 then 1 else 0 END)) *100,1) as mtd
     . . .
FROM CTE
```

This may speed up the query.  In addition, you could then incorporate this logic into the CTE query itself, eliminating the materialization step as well.

Comment: I tried with the method you've answered me. But if I run the query. I get error `syntax error at or near "then"`.